Function to Convert string to Hexadecimal
Assignment:
Create a function that can convert a string to its encoded hexadecimal value.

In your answer, also show how to run this function (to validate answers).
Your function must return OR print this text to STDOUT or any acceptable alternative.
Your return value doesn't need to have whitespace between hexadecimal pairs.
You may not use libraries/packages in general and any other functions that directly converts a string to hexadecimal. For example, using a function or package to convert the string to bytes is OK.
This is Code Golf, so shortest code wins.

Example Input:
Input Example:
Hello World!

Output Examples:
48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21

OR

48656c6c6f20576f726c6421


Welcome to Code Golf. See How does the Sandbox work?

Node.JS, 141 bytes
f=s=>{b=new TextEncoder().encode(s),h='';for(_ of b){H=(_>>4)&0x0F,l=_&0x0F,h+=String.fromCharCode(H+(H<10?48:87),l+(l<10?48:87))};return h;}

Usage
f("Hello World!")

Returns
48656c6c6f20576f726c6421

